# Cron scheduling frequency issue

Tags: magento-2.1, crontab

I have an issue with a custom cron scheduling on Magento EE 2.1.4. I would like to run my crons every hour. I based my crontab.xml on the "index" cron group in my custom module. Below, my crontab.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="index">
        <job name="custom_geocoding" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Geo" method="execute">
            <schedule>* */1 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
         <job name="custom_sage_import" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\SageImport" method="execute">
            <schedule>* */1 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

My crons are executed every minute, what is the problem?

Comment: The issue is solved with the solution of Sachin Agarwal!

Answer (score 1):

Try `<schedule>0 * * * *</schedule>` instead please.